# Direct user on certain page after purchased plan use velo code

Tags: velo

How to direct user on certain page after successful payment on membership plan using velo code ? cause on wix the users was direct into thank you page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pricing-plans you have one editable page but in fact you have three page.

- First one is where you list your plans. /pricing-plans/ Second one is
- where the payment made. /pricing-plans/payment/ Last one is where the
- thank you page is. /pricing-plans/status/

What you need to do is use wix-location and when URL changes to /pricing-plans/status/ send user to another URL.

Here is an example code inside pricing-plans page in editor.

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

$w.onReady(() => {
    wixLocation.onChange((location) => {
        if (wixLocation.url.includes("/pricing-plans/status/")) {
            wixLocation.to("redirectedUrl");
        }
    });
})
```

pricing-plans can be different for your site it's the URL that you choose and you can change so check that before.